# Google Action possible bug: After SIGN_IN doesn't show List widget

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm developing a Google Action with DialogFlow and I think I found a bug in Google Assistant App:

In Default Welcome Intent there is the possibility to sign in with an external website (OAuth2), in webhook:

```
app.intent(INTENT_WELCOME_YES, conv => {
  if (conv.hasScreen) {
     conv.ask(new SignIn());
  } else {
     conv.ask("Welcome!");
  }
});
```

And i noticed that if I **don't conv.ask the SignIn object**, the application with display runs correctly (image below)

[image]

Insted, if **I choose to send Sign In**, then, only List object like the image before does not renders anymore. Request/response to/from webhook are the same.

[image]

Do someone knows a workaround?

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you're saying. Does the sign-in not work? Are you expecting to see something else with the sign-in? Can you show the conversation flow and what isn't working at each stage and the code (and Intents) that you're trying at each stage?

Comment: Sing-in works but, it's graphic elements that doesen't works anymore. I mean, in a flow whithout sending the Singin() object, everything is fine, instead if I send it, only conv.ask(new List(..)); stop working in Google Assistant display. anyway I will enrich the answer

Comment: Can you create gist with sample code?